# Macro throws a weird error while parsing content from json

Tags: json, vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to scrape certain information from a [webpage](https://www.redfin.com/TX/Austin/604-Amesbury-Ln-78752/unit-2/home/171045975) using xmlhttp requests. The information I'm interested in are javascript encrypted and loaded dynamically. However, they are available in page source (CTRL + U).

When I scoop out that portion from page source using regex and process the same using  `JsonConverter`, I get the following error:

```
Run-time error `10001`:
Error parsing JSON:
"text":{"payload":{"
```

I've tried with:

```
Sub GrabRedfinInfo()
    Const siteLink$ = "https://www.redfin.com/TX/Austin/604-Amesbury-Ln-78752/unit-2/home/171045975"
    Dim HTML As HTMLDocument, Http As Object
    Dim jsonObject As Object, jsonStr As Object
    Dim itemStr As Variant, sResp As String

    Set HTML = New HTMLDocument
    Set Http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    With Http
        .Open "Get", siteLink, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        HTML.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        sResp = .responseText
    End With

    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "reactServerState\.InitialContext = (.*);"
        .MultiLine = True
        Set jsonStr = .Execute(sResp)
    End With
    
    itemStr = jsonStr(0).submatches(0)
    
    Set jsonObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(Replace(itemStr, "\", ""))
    MsgBox jsonObject("ReactServerAgent.cache")("dataCache")("/stingray/api/home/details/belowTheFold")("res")
End Sub
```

Expected output:

```
Active Under Contract
Active
Pending - Taking Backups
Active
```

The following image shows their whereabouts:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPSxv.jpg

Comment: The following two lines are the fix. First replace your existing line with this `Set jsonObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(itemStr)` and then add `("text")` to get the string `MsgBox jsonObject("ReactServerAgent.cache")("dataCache")("/stingray/api/home/details/belowTheFold")("res")("text")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would instead alter the regex to be more restrictive and target only the events governing string. I would additionally alter the string replacement to ensure I was exchanging `\"` with `"`.

You then end up with the timeline of events as an array/collection. See [here](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?#left=cloud.346070a7d8264496a93c2c38d3f8ad3b&right=local.sazese)

---

**Example:**

[image]

---

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GrabRedfinInfo()
    Const siteLink$ = "https://www.redfin.com/TX/Austin/604-Amesbury-Ln-78752/unit-2/home/171045975"
    Dim HTML As HTMLDocument, Http As Object
    Dim jsonObject As Object, jsonStr As Object
    Dim itemStr As Variant, sResp As String

    Set HTML = New HTMLDocument
    Set Http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    With Http
        .Open "Get", siteLink, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        HTML.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        sResp = .responseText
    End With

    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = """events\\"".(\[.*?\])"
        .MultiLine = True
        Set jsonStr = .Execute(sResp)
    End With
    
    itemStr = jsonStr(0).SubMatches(0)
    
    Set jsonObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(Replace$(itemStr, "\" & Chr$(34), Chr$(34))) 'Array (collection)
    
    Dim evt As Object
    
    For Each evt In jsonObject
        Debug.Print evt("mlsDescription")
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly. Could you shade light on why the very error showed up when I tried it my way? Thanks.

Comment: I assume your replace isn't actually fixing the json. Possibly you are introducing a different invalidation through the replacement. It is tricky when it comes to escaping correctly within a string you want to parse as json later.